# Windows 8 Geolocation

Tags: c#, .net, windows, geolocation

I'm trying to debug a location issue with my Windows 8 RT app.  I can't even get the MSDN example to run properly, the exception is:

An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

I'm confident it's nothing I'm doing since this is the MSDN example I simply downloaded and tried to run.

Comment: To follow up, no apps are working when trying to get my location.  No MSDN examples, Bing Maps just sits there, all other apps fail (weatherbug, etc.)

Comment: _all other apps fail_ - so it's more of a system / config issue?

Comment: If all other apps fail, then this has nothing to do with your C# code. Like Henk said, it is likely a system issue.

Comment: Def. a system issue, but I can't figure out where...

Comment: It's not a tablet.  This is my development machine, its a Dell Optiplex e6750, Core 2 Duo 2.66Ghz, 2 GB ram...I'm reinstalling Windows 8 on another machine to test

Comment: Excuse me if I got this wrong, but how are you using Win8 RT on a x86 processor?

Comment: I'm building an application targeting Windows RT, the same thing occurs if I choose to target x86 as well.

Comment: Stupid question, does you x86 machine even have a Geolocation sensor?

Comment: The GeoLocator class should use his IP address if the machine doesn't have a Geolocation sensor. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225603.aspx

Comment: That's correct, it uses IP if no Geolocation sensor is detected.  Turns out this was an issue with the OS and hardware not playing nicely together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is something with my dev machine.  I installed on a newer Dell laptop running a Core i5 processor and it works fine.